# How can I bring back the proposition for war in Stelaris?

Tags: stellaris

I accidentally closed it without voting, how can I find it? When I suggest declaring war on the target it says there's already a proposition to do so.

Comment: Odds are when you closed it, if the alert is no longer at the top, it's been auto-declined.

Comment: If there is a warscore icon in the bottom-right of the screen, did you try to click on it?

Comment: @GillesV. There wasn't. The vote hadn't finished so no war was declared yet. Sometime later (if I remember correctly) the vote failed because I presumably abstained or voted against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no way to bring the war proposition back, as when you close it it's counted as the default option, which is against.

If you still want to declare war, you have to wait the end of the vote and suggest the war again.

Comment: In my (limited) experience thus far, another war deceleration proposition will be suggested again soon enough. When allies want to go to war, they seem pretty persistent about it.